# changing css style with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Am I changing the style correctly? I am trying to change overflow-x to scroll.  It's not working.

css

```
div.anythingSlider .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow {
margin-top: 15px;
overflow-x:hidden;
float: left;
}
```

js

```
$("div.anythingSlider .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow").css({"overflow-x":"scroll"});
```

Comment: This code isn't changing a class.. it's adding some css.

Comment: Please tag and describe your questions correctly.  It's got nothing to do with html5 and you're changing styles, not classes.

Comment: Im just trying to change overflow-x to scroll

Comment: Is the -1 vote only to get others get more preference? I don't know why I am getting -1. Please explain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are doing there is selecting all elements that correspond to the selector "div.anythingSlider .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow", but not changing the class definition itself. If you want to change the class maybe you need to fiddle a little with additional classes, so your CSS sheet looks like this:

```
div.anythingSlider .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow {
  margin-top: 15px;
  overflow-x:hidden;
  float: left;
}

div.anythingSlider.withOverflow .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow {
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

This way you can select with jQuery the anythingSlider element you want to change and do something like:

```
$("div.anythingSlider").addClass("withOverflow")
```

Answer (score 1):

Your example isn't changing a class, you are overriding the class by changing inline styles with jQuery.

Depending on the browser you're using, the `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` properties are sometimes ignored **unless *both* are defined**. You probably just need to specify a value for `overflow-y` in your class.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please give a try: (just guess)

```
$("div.anythingSlider .anythingControls .anythingNavWindow").css("overflow-x", "scroll");
```

Comment: please at least give a comment when you are downvoting. I need to correct myself if I was wrong.

Comment: You shouldn't just give a -1 for your own purpose.

Answer (score 0):

This statement doesn't change the CSS class definition; it applies the `overflow-x: scroll` style to the matched selector elements.